# Meteor.http.get always returns error

Tags: meteor, http-headers

I'm trying a http.get and it always returns error from the server. The same url answers with success using both postman and chrome. 
I'm new to Meteor.

```
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
    var url = "http://dadosabertos.rio.rj.gov.br/apiTransporte/apresentacao/rest/index.cfm/obterPosicoesDaLinha/217";

    HTTP.get(url, {timeout:30000}, function (error, result) {
        console.log(error);
        if (!error) {
            console.log(respose.statusCode, result.data); 
        }
    });
}, 60000);

I20140608-18:26:28.512(-3)? { [Error: failed [400]]
I20140608-18:26:28.513(-3)?   response: 
I20140608-18:26:28.513(-3)?    { statusCode: 400,
I20140608-18:26:28.513(-3)?      content: '',
I20140608-18:26:28.513(-3)?      headers: 
I20140608-18:26:28.513(-3)?       { date: 'Sun, 08 Jun 2014 21:26:29 GMT',
I20140608-18:26:28.514(-3)?         server: 'Apache',
I20140608-18:26:28.514(-3)?         vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
I20140608-18:26:28.514(-3)?         'access-control-allow-origin': '*',
I20140608-18:26:28.514(-3)?         connection: 'close',
I20140608-18:26:28.514(-3)?         'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
I20140608-18:26:28.514(-3)?         'content-type': 'text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' },
I20140608-18:26:28.515(-3)?      data: null } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling I decided to test the http header from a successful get. Live HTTP Headers was the tool to get the header value.

The complete header made things better, I got a 200 but some gibberish as data.

The final test and solution was **{headers: {Accept: '*/*'}}** as options value.

It seems the server I'm getting data from did wrong since the [HTTP/1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) states: "If no Accept header field is present, then it is assumed that the client accepts all media types".

[HTTP.get(url, [options], [asyncCallback])](http://docs.meteor.com/#http_get)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking at an outdated documentation or something, but I believe the current way of going HTTP GETs in Meteor is to use `HTTP.get` (http://docs.meteor.com/#http_get).

Comment: Thanks, Christian. I updated the code, but the issue is still the same.